# Best way to identify duplicates in two lists or a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, python-3.7

Lets say you have two lists such as:

```
list1 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9]
```

...and the two lists were zipped into a dictionary to produce:

```
dict1 = {-2: 4, 
         -1: 1, 
          0: 0, 
          1: 1, 
          2: 4, 
          3: 9}
```

...where list1 is the key, and list 2 is the value.

You will notice that some of the elements in list2 are duplicates such as 4 and 1. They show up twice in list 2, and consequently in the dictionary.

```
-2 corresponds to 4
 2 corresponds to 4
-1 corresponds to 1
 1 corresponds to 1
```

I am trying to figure out a way **either using the lists or the dictionary** to identify the duplicate items in list2, and return their keys from list 1.

So the returned values I would expect from the two lists above would be:

```
(-2, 2) #From list 1 since they both correspond to 4 in list2
(-1, 1) #from list 1 since they both correspond to 1 in list2
```

In this example, list2 happens to be the square of list1. But this will not always be the case.

So ultimately, what I am looking for is a way to return those keys based on their duplicate values.

Any thoughts on how to approach this? I am able to identify the duplicates in list2, but I am completely stuck on how to identify their corresponding values in list 1.

Comment: Can you re-frame the question. Completely confused

Comment: I reframed the question, sorry if it was confusing!

Comment: You got duplicates (groupby, where count >1, select or yield). For each duplicate in list2, you can yield all corresponding keys.

Comment: @Soleil Do I groupby on list 2? How will that yield the values in list1?

Answer (score 0):

In python3:

```
from itertools import groupby
list1 = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9]
pairs = zip(list2, list1)
ordered = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[0])
groups = ((k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(ordered, key=lambda x: x[0])) # generator
duplicates = (k for k in groups if len(k[1])>1) # generator
for k,v in duplicates :
    print(str(k) + " : " + str(list(v)))
```

result:

```
1 : [(1, -1), (1, 1)]
4 : [(4, -2), (4, 2)]
```

Bonus: in functional c#:

```
var list1 = new[] { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new[] { 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9 };
var g = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => (a, b)) //create tuples
    .GroupBy(o => o.b, o => o.a, (k, group) => new { key = k, group = group.ToList() }) //create groups
    .Where(o => o.group.Count > 1) // select group with minimum 2 elements
    .ToList(); // no lazy
foreach (var kvp in g)
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.key}: {string.Join(",", kvp.group)}");
```

result:

```
4: -2,2
1: -1,1
```